# How to check if a file is within a directory

Tags: perl, file, foreach, directory, exists

I have a text file with a list of individual mnemonics (1000+) in it and a directory that also has page files in it. I want to see how many pages a given mnemonic is on.

below is my code so far..

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use File::Find ();

my $mnemonics = "path\\path\\mnemonics.txt";
my $pages = "path\\path\\pages\\";

open (INPUT_FILE, $names) or die "Cannot open file $mnemonics\n";
my @mnemonic_list = <INPUT_FILE>;
close (INPUT_FILE);

opendir (DH, $pages);
my @pages_dir = readdir DH;

foreach my $mnemonic (@mnemonic_list) {
    foreach my $page (@pages_dir) {
        if (-e $mnemonic) {
            print "$mnemonic is in the following page: $page";
        }  else {
            print "File does not exist \n";
        }
    }
}
```

Basically, where I know that a name exists in a page, it isn't showing me the correct output. I'm getting a lot of "File does not exists" when I know it does.

Also, instead of (-e) I tried using:

```
if ($name =~ $page)
```

and that didn't work either..

Please help!

Comment: What do the entries in mnemonics look like?

Comment: they're just words, entered on new lines. It's about 1000 words +

Comment: Do you want to look inside the files or just at the file names?

Comment: I want it to look inside the files that are in the directory "pages" and use the txt file names to see if they're in there... does that make sense? sorry!!

Comment: Are those supposed to be absolute paths? If so, they should begin with a double backslash. (Actually, you can change all the double backslashes to single forward slashes, even on Windows.)

Comment: it has no problem reading the paths in the beginning, because I tested it with a print $pages and it spit out the names, and then a print $mnemonics and it did print out all the lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you want to search a directory full of text files and print the names of files that contain words from the words in mnemonics.txt, try this:

```
use strict; use warnings;

my $mnemonics = "path/mnemonics.txt";
my $pages = "path/pages/";

open (INPUT_FILE, $mnemonics) or die "Cannot open file $mnemonics\n";
chomp(my @mnemonic_list = <INPUT_FILE>);
close (INPUT_FILE);

local($/, *FILE);          # set "slurp" mode
for my $filename (<$pages*>) {
  next if -d "$filename";  # ignore subdirectories
  open FILE, "$filename";
  binmode(FILE);
  $filename =~ s/.+\///;   # remove path from filename for output
  my $contents = <FILE>;   # "slurp" file contents
  for my $mnemonic (@mnemonic_list) {
    if ($contents =~ /$mnemonic/i) {
      print "'$mnemonic' found in file $filename\n";
    }
  }
  close FILE;
}
```

Comment: the pages directory does not have text files in it

Comment: awesome this worked great! except one thing... what if there is more than one page that it appears in? It only output the first page the mnemonics were in...

Comment: What type of files are they?

Comment: the reason I figured this would work is because I can bring up a search in windows and type the mnemonic i'm looking for and it'll spit out the pages its in..

Comment: An .hdp file is some kind of image file. So it's a binary file, and should be read in binary mode (see revised code above). It probably still won't work, though. Maybe the text strings are encoded inside the file as wide characters? I'm unsure how to deal with that.

Comment: OMG IT WORKED. THANK YOU SO MUCH! what exactly does "s./\///" do??

Comment: s stands for "substitute". The basic form is `s/pattern/replacement/`. Between the first two I put `.+\/` which matches a string of at least one character ending in a forward slash (the forward slash is preceeded by a backslash so it is not interpretted as the forward slash that ends the pattern). The replacement string is empty. So it replaces everything up to and including the first forward slash with nothing.